# What is the minimum number of integers chosen from $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ so that there are always three of them whose sum is $15$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Edit: Comments showed me the answer is 7. How can I prove that using pigeonhole?

I know this is a pigeonhole principle question and that $6$ integers is enough to guarantee the condition, but I'm having trouble figuring out the appropriate pigeons/pigeonholes. Here are a few thoughts, though I don't know how useful they are:

- There are $8$ possible triplets from $\{1,2,...,9\}$ that sum to $15$: $\{1,5,9\},
     \{1,6,8\}, \{2,4,9\}, \{2,5,8\}, \{2,6,7\}, \{3,4,8\}, \{3,5,7\}, \{4,5,6\}$.
- From $6$ integers there are $20$ possible triplets, and from
  $S$ the minimum triplet sum is $1+2+3=6$, and the maximum is
  $7+8+9=24$, giving us a range of $19$ possible sums.
- In order for a triplet to sum to $15$, the sum of its smallest integers
  must be at least $6$, and the sum of its largest integers must be at
  most $14$.

I think I'm missing some crucial observation.

Comment: Probably the answer is 2 ?

Comment: I said about the minimum number of integers that have to be added to get 15.

Comment: Oops ! I didn't know that I have to choose a triplet !

Comment: Look at the magic square

Comment: Are you sure $6$ are enough? What about $1,2,3,7,8,9$?

Comment: I thought of $\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,9\rbrace $.

Comment: @SamRubenAbraham That has $1+5+9=15$. There is another set of 6 without a triplet: $1,3,4,6,7,9$. This is just a mirrored or rotated version of bof's counterexample when viewed on the 3x3 magic square.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis would it be 7 then? If so, I still don't know what the pigeon and pigeonholes would be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is $7$.

You need at least $7$ because no three of the $6$ numbers $1,2,3,7,8,9$ add up to $15$.

Looking at your $8$ possible triplets that sum to $15$, no number belongs to more than $4$ triplets, and only the number $5$ belongs to $4$ triplets, no other number belongs to more than $3$ triplets. Therefore if you choose any $7$ numbers from $S$, the two missing numbers are in at most $4+3=7$ triplets between them, so there is at least one triplet you haven't avoided.

Comment: An easier argument to prove 7 is by pigeonhole: Choosing 7 numbers from the three sets $\{1,6,8\}$, $\{3,5,7\}$, $\{2,4,9\}$ results in 3 from the same set.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis perfect, thanks so much

Comment: @bof nice elegant argument.